# PHP Form validation server side, Display error on page, Display outputs on other page

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate a form using server-side, but the problem is, I can't display the error message and inputs. To explain it in details:

- Have a form that can post inputs
- Validate the data eg,. if empty, display error on the page, else proceed to the target page

form page, this is where I validate and display

```
   <?php

  ?>
<?=$firstErr?>
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" name="firstname" />

<input type="text" name="secondname" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" >
</form>
```

target page

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $first = $_POST['firstname'];
    $second = $_POST['secondname'];

    if($first == "" && $second== "")
    {

        echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'main.php';</script>";
        $firstErr .= '<p class="error">Username should be alpha numeric characters only.</p>';
    }   

    else
    {
        echo $first; 
        echo $second;
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you want to display the error staying on the same page? you're currently do a redirect to main.php which of course won't display error message from $firstErr as you probably expect.

Comment: All I need is to display errors like if the field is null on the same page, but if no error, it will go to the output page.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have already been redirected to the page before the line execution.

Instead add an alert like this.

```
if($first == "" && $second== "")
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Username should be alpha numeric characters only.');</script>"; //<-- Added here
        echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'main.php';</script>";
    }
```

Comment: alert is one way but what I need is to display the error message beside the input textbox.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to  go back to main.php the javascript simply loads that page.

As far as I know, you will have to implmenent some sort of a checking method that will store your error codes on sessions or cookies and then write a check to display the messages if there are errors. You will have to clear the errors saved once main.php is loaded by the way.
Or you can pass on the error messages through $_GET by modifying your javascript.

Your javascript could look like

```
window.location = "main.php?err=1";
```

You can set your main.php to

```
 if(isset($_GET['err'])) {
       //Your logic to check the error message number and display text goes here
   }
```

Ideal would be to verify on the client side using javascript/jquery but since you mentioned this to be a server side verification you will have to either use a framework that has all the foundation laid for such kind form validation (using a framework has many pros and cons so I am not sure if this feasible to you. Just putting it out there), or write your own small logic to check and revert back to the main page with the error codes.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the redirect occurs and the PHP isn't executed. What you can do is set a `GET` param in your redirect.

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'main.php?error=1';</script>";
```

And on main.php

```
if(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == 1) { do code ... }
```

Comment: I tested this, when I accidentally click the submit button, the ?error=1 changed to the name of the page, I wonder if the problem is caused by adding action="somepage.php" to the form